# How does the name "Marauder's Map" indicate that its creators are "the Marauders"?

Tags: harry-potter, marauders-map

Referring to the group of James, Sirius, Lupin, and Pettigrew as "the Marauders" seems to be pretty ubiquitous. There are many such references to them on this site alone; on a popular fanfiction site, there is an entire category called "Marauder Era".

In fact, in the books themselves there is at least one reference to "the Marauders". In Chapter Twenty-One of *Half-Blood Prince*, in reference to the Room of Requirement, we find the following statement:

> "Maybe the Marauders never knew the room was there," said Ron.

However, it is unclear to me where this comes from. As far as I can tell, every time it appears in the books the name of the map is spelled "Marauder's" and not "Marauders'". In the former it is a singular possessive, while the latter would be a plural possessive. If the name was meant to be saying that this was the map of the Marauders – i.e. that it is the map owned/created/used by four people who went by the name "Marauders" – we would expect it to in fact be called the Marauders' map. The fact that it is called the Marauder's map makes it seem like it is a map for a Marauder – i.e. it is a map to help any wayward student get into mischief, with the typological wayward student being referred to as a marauder.

Am I missing something here? How do we get from "the Marauder's map" to a group of people who are specifically known as "the Marauders"?

Comment: Perhaps they named the map first and liked it enough to use it for their group identity.

Comment: This is yet another example of how Rowling sucks at math.

Comment: @Alarion That's certainly a theoretical possibility, but how does anyone know that?

Comment: I think you're reading waaaaay too much into this. It's not really that much of a stretch to go from Marauder's to Marauders and it is an every day mistake even in our world. In fact I'd even state it makes sense without the mistake. Marauder's Map - a map for a Marauder, 4 people made it so they are Marauders, call them the Marauders. Seems quite reasonable to me.

Comment: Because, despite what generations of English teachers have tried to pound into their students' heads, That's Not How Grammar Works. (Language is what we *say* it is. Writing, especially a dinky little apostrophe, is entirely secondary.)

Comment: Since there seems to be some confusion: are you asking whether (in canon) James, Sirius, Lupin, and Pettigrew referred to themselves and/or were referred to as "The Marauders" while they were at Hogwarts?

Comment: @HarryJohnston More than just did they refer to themselves that way. How does anyone know that they referred to themselves that way?

Comment: @Alex, as per the discussion under ADavidson's answer, Sirius might well have reminisced about his days in Hogwarts with Ron and Hermione in OotP?

Comment: @HarryJohnston An off-screen conversation with Sirius could explain how characters like Ron would know about it, though it wouldn't explain how readers knew it (particularly before *Half-Blood Prince* was published).

Comment: Do you have any particular evidence that readers in general believed this?  All I can say of my own knowledge is that *I* didn't. :-)  Or are you talking about fanfiction writers?  'cause they're kinda known for just making stuff up, you know?

Comment: @HarryJohnston As mentioned in the question it is pretty ubiquitous, even on this site. For instance, a search of “the marauders were” on this site turns up many instances in which the characters are referred to as the Marauders.

Comment: Um.  In my opinion, and based on an admittedly very brief look at a possibly-not-random-enough sampling, the term is used here mostly in the same way Ron used it: descriptively.  The fact that *we* call them The Marauders isn't automatically an implied assertion that they called themselves that.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That gets to the crux of the question. How did we decide to refer to them as “the Marauders”? If they had created a map for new students and called it “the First Year’s Map” I doubt we would refer to them as “the First  Years”.

Comment: ... only because that would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

JK Rowling stated they dubbed themselves the mauraders

On the FAQ of the old JKRowling.com FAQ, one of the entries is:

> On your website, you used the term "marauders" to refer to James and
>   his friends. Were they actually called that or are you just borrowing
>   the fan term? [Mugglenet/Lexicon question]
>
> **James, Sirius, Remus and Peter dubbed themselves ‘marauders’, hence
>   the way they titled the map.**

https://web.archive.org/web/20060316221607/https://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=87

Comment: This is, of course, a retcon.

Answer (score 2):

The map does not "belong" to "the Marauders". They were the ones that created it, but the lack of any protective spells on it, restricting its use to *only* Mooney, Wormtail, Padfoot and Prongs, means that they never intended to keep it purely for themselves. The only indicator that they are the ones that created it is the fact that their names are on the map itself.

> He took out his wand, touched the parchment lightly and said, ‘I solemnly swear that I am up to no good.’
>
> And at once, thin ink lines began to spread like a spider’s web from the point that George’s wand had touched. They joined each other, they criss-crossed, they fanned into every corner of the parchment; then words began to blossom across the top, great, curly green words, that proclaimed: *Messrs Moony, Wormtail, Padfoot and Prongs Purveyors of Aids to Magical Mischief-Makers are proud to present THE MARAUDER’S MAP.*

The only keywords are "I solemnly swear I am up to no good", and "Mischief managed". This means that anyone who knows what this map is, can use it; thus making them a "Marauder", which explains the "Marauder's Map". It is a map, created by a group of 4 individuals, labelled as "The Marauders", that is a tool for any future "Marauder" that finds the map, and learns its uses.

The only other reference I can think of that would identify the original 4 as the creators of the map, is the use of the title "Messrs":

> plural of Mr  (= title used before a man's name) used before the names of two or more men, usually in the title of a company:
>
> *Messrs Wood and Laurence, solicitors*

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/messrs)

In this case, the "company" would be "The Marauders", who have created the tool, called "the Marauder's Map".

---

All that said, J.K Rowling specifically states that the map was created by, and belonged to James, Remus, Sirius and Peter (emphasis mine):

> The ability of Sirius Black, Peter Pettigrew and James Potter to become, respectively, a dog, a rat and a stag, **enabled them to explore the castle grounds by night undetected. The interior of the castle, meanwhile, was mapped over time with the help of James Potter’s Invisibility Cloak.**
>
> The Marauder’s Map is lasting testimony to the advanced magical ability of the four friends who included Harry Potter’s father, godfather and favourite teacher. **The map they created during their time at Hogwarts** appears to be a blank piece of parchment unless activated by the phrase: ‘I solemnly swear that I am up to no good,’ a phrase that, in the case of three of the four makers, should be understood as a joke. **The ‘no good’ of which they wrote never denoted Dark magic, but school rule-breaking; similar bravado is evinced by their use of their own nicknames on the map (‘Messrs Moony, Wormtail, Padfoot and Prongs’)**.

[Source](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-marauders-map)

**Edit:** As you have quoted in your question, Ron refers to the original 4 as the "Marauders". This is not really anything official, just a reference to them as the map creators. Outside of this, there is no hard connection between the label, and the group.

It is less wordy than "Mooney, Wormtail, Padfoot and Prongs", and it is a fairly common practice to label groups by a common factor. I.e. "the Slytherins".

The reason this is not more widely used is simply due to the knowledge of this particular group being known to only a limited few.

Comment: The map belongs the them because they created it, and it is password protected. The probability that anyone would find the password are low. They may have intended to pass it on after school.

Comment: The link I provided to the Pottermore site does go on to say that Filch's acquisition of the map is not covered, nor how the Twins discovered the "passwords" for it, but the circumstances leading to the creation of the Order of the Phoenix took priority over recovering the map, and its usefulness no longer of any importance.

Comment: I’m not questioning whether they created the map. My question is how we know that “Marauders” ever represented a specific group of four people.

Comment: @Alex ….because Lupin said so. He told Harry that the group made the map

Comment: @NKCampbell Did he actually say that “the Marauders” made it?

Comment: @Alex - yes - if you put the pieces together. First, the map says "Moony, Wormtail, Padfoot, and Prongs, Purveyors of Aids to Magical Mischief Makers are proud to present the Maurauder's Map" - purveyors could mean just seller, but also maker. Second, when Snape finds the map, he direcly questions Lupin asking if Harry didn't get it "directly from the manufacturers" - pointedly directly the question at Lupin. Snape knows who made it. Harry even asks Lupin why Snape asked that. Lupin says "......because [with hesitation], these mapmakers would have wanted to lure you out of school."...

Comment: @Alex …. finally, when Lupin gives the map back to Harry at the end, Harry asks "You told me Moony, Wormtail, Padfoot, and Prongs, would've wanted to lure me out of school, you said they'd have thought it was funny...." to which Lupin replies "And so *we* would have done."

So - Lupin says the manufacturers would have wanted to lure Harry out of school and he later confirms that he and James, etc...where the manufacturers

Comment: @NKCampbell That shows that the people that we call “the Marauders” created the map. But it doesn’t show that those people are actually called “the Marauders”.

Answer (score -2):

The idea that James and his friends are called the marauders is pure fanon with no basis in the books. It started because some early fans didn't understand how apostrophes work and took "marauder's" to mean "marauders". It's possible that JK retconned this later in an interview, but in the original books there's no indication of "The Marauders".

edit: yes, there is mention of "The Marauders" later on, but that was in later books that came out years afterwards, long after it had become firmly established in the fandom. It wasn't in the original Azkaban book. It's a retcon.

Comment: Except that the very question you're answering includes a quote from the books in which they're called the Marauders.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, only by Ron, though, and how would he know?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - JK has always taken great pains to have Ron corrected (either explicitly by Hermione or implicitly via events) anytime he's said anything actually wrong in-universe iirc

Comment: See my comments on Ben's answer - I argue that it can be read as being clear in the 3rd book that they are the mauraders. Also my answer cites word of god that they dubbed themselves that

Comment: @NKCampbell, well, that's the general rule in fiction - but only when it is actually something important to the plot, which this isn't.  I don't think that means that every offhand comment of Ron's (or anyone else's) is canon truth unless explicitly contradicted - particularly if it is obvious in context that there is no way the person speaking could possibly know.

Comment: (Which isn't to say that Ron is mistaken here; he isn't in fact asserting that they called themselves the Marauders, after all, it's just an obvious way to describe them.)

Comment: but Ron could possibly know. He was around half of the remaining Mauraders for some time. It's quite possible he heard stories from Lupin and Sirius

Comment: @NKCampbell, oops, I'd misidentified the source of the quote, thought it was from PoA.  My mistake.  This was, of course, after Ron and Hermione spent quite some time off-panel in Grimmauld Place, so yes, the subject could easily have come up.